# WSO2 using sensitive credentials in proxies without storing them

Tags: amazon-web-services, wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

So I need to find a way to use sensitive details(authentication username, password etc) in my wso2 proxies and sequences without hardcoding them or extracting them from a local entry(like I am currently). In production my wso2 mi is deployed in aws, and I want to be able to store the passwords somewhere where they get extracted only on deployment and then used.

I was reading about storing passwords in a file or in a yaml in aws,but i'm not sure what would be the optimal solution...
So far i'm storing my credentials in a local entry and they are referenced from there by my sequences. I don't want to use a secret vault either.

Answer (score 3):

The most secure way is to use Secure Vault to encrypt the passwords and inject them into the `deployment.toml` when deploying the server. Take a look at [this](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/setup/security/encrypting_plain_text/). Then you can use them like below within your integration.

```xml
<property expression="wso2:vault-lookup('synapse_secret')" name="secret"/>
```

If you are ok to store sensitive values in plain text. You can store the values in a properties file called `file.properties`. If you are using a different fileName you can pass it to the server startup script like `-Dproperties.file.path=/home/dev/dev.properties`. Then you can read them through a [Property Mediator](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/mediators/property-Mediator/). Check [this](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/mediators/property-reference/accessing-properties-with-xpath/#file-scope). Example below.

```xml
<property expression="get-property('file', String propertyName)" name="secret"/>
```